# Data binding causes memory leak even the binding has been nullified

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, android-databinding, android-architecture-navigation

I've done my research on memory leak when using Data Binding. Every posts said that one should assign `null` to binding object to resolve this issue. However, it just doesn't work.

I've created two identical Fragments with a single Activity. Each Fragment includes a button which can be used to navigate to one another.

To reproduce this issue, **click the button repeatedly**, LeakCanary will pop up the memory leak warning. (However, the issue does not occur when clicking the buttons "programmatically")

#### Repro

[image]

#### LeakCanary

[image: LeakCanary]

#### Code

The following is the code of my Fragments. (Two fragments are identical)

##### FirstFragment.kt

```kotlin
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.btnFirst.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_to_second)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

##### fragment_first.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FirstFragment">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first_fragment" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="To second" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

##### SecondFragment.kt

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentSecondBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentSecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.btnSecond.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_to_first)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

##### fragment_second.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SecondFragment">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/second_fragment" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="To first" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

I've also created a [repo](https://github.com/Doge-is-Dope/MemoryLeakSample) in case someone want to try it out.

Let me know if I can provide any further information.
Thanks!

Comment: Your leak is around `SecondFragment`, not `FirstFragment`. Can you include the code for `SecondFragment`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for the quick reply! I've included the code for `SecondFragment`.

Comment: Weird !!! if thats the Only code u have in Second Fragment .. It should not leak .. Can u try once uninstalling the build and reinstall it again ..

Comment: @ADM I reinstalled the app on emulator and physical device. Still, the leak occurs

Comment: Does it help to move `super.onDestroyView()` line after the `_binding = null` line?

Comment: @LucaPizzini HI, I've included the layouts. Thanks!

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for the reply! It still leaks tho

Comment: I build your code (from repository) on a API 30 device. It doesn't have any leak.

Comment: @beigirad Hi! Have you tried to click the buttons repeatedly?

Comment: @clement.l yeah, of course. I tried mixing those buttons, back button and rotating screen also.

Comment: @beigirad Hmmm...That's weird! I keep getting leaks on emulators and physical devices. Thanks for the testing anyway!

Comment: To all whom may have run into this issue, the developer team of leakcanaray has found the source and marked the leak as known leak.
https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/2341

Answer (score 0):

To all whom may have run into this issue, the developer team of leakcanaray has found the source and marked the leak as known issue.

[github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/2341](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/2341)

A related issue can be found on [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229136453).